# Using R, how can I transpose a list of names and identifiers into a table with a different number of items in each column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a list of names and departments with different numbers of names per each department. An example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~NAME,      ~DEPT,
  "Emma",     "Tox",
  "Sophia",   "CP",
  "Liam",     "QP",
  "Noah",     "QP", 
  "Olivia",   "Tox", 
  "Isabella", "QP",
  "Muhammed", "QP",
  "Abdullah", "QP",
  "Lea",      "Tox",
  "Matteo",   "CP")
```

What I want is to transpose this list into something like the below:

```
df_table <- tribble(
  ~CP,      ~QP,        ~Tox,
  "Sophia", "Abdullah", "Emma",   
  "Matteo", "Isabella", "Lea",
  NA,       "Liam",     "Olivia",
  NA,       "Muhammed", NA,
  NA,       "Noah",     NA)
```

Note, I'd like the individual columns to be alphabetically sorted and to have blanks be represented as NAs or ""s. Ideally, I'd also like the script to extract a unique list of departments to generate the columns in the final table but not crucial.

For small lists, this can all be done manually. However, my actual list is a) longer and b) constantly changing. I'd like to automate the creation of this table so I can maintain a CSV with the names/departments and just run the code through RMarkdown to create the roster table on a slide.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);library(data.table); df %>% mutate(rn = rowid(DEPT)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = DEPT, values_from = NAME)`

Comment: Try `data.frame(lapply(a<-unstack(df), \`length<-\`, max(lengths(a))))`

Comment: @akrun, that works perfectly. ChatGPT proposed something similar, but yours was slightly more parsimonious. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
 mutate(rn = rowid(DEPT)) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = DEPT, values_from = NAME)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
dcast(df, rowid(DEPT) ~ DEPT, value.var = 'NAME')[, -1]
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do:

```
data.frame(lapply(a<-unstack(df), `length<-`, max(lengths(a))))

      CP       QP    Tox
1 Sophia     Liam   Emma
2 Matteo     Noah Olivia
3   <NA> Isabella    Lea
4   <NA> Muhammed   <NA>
5   <NA> Abdullah   <NA>
```

Comment: This definitely works, but the formatting is slightly cleaner with the other answer proposed by akrun. If I had a better named dataset, I'd probably use this solution.

Comment: @jsgraydon yes you can use tidyverse alone for this. I was providing a base R solution. This is just one way of solving the problem